# How do I extract a password protected .7z file?

Tags: server, command-line, extract

Can someone tell me how can I extract a password protected .7z file in Ubuntu server?

(I know the password, I just need a program to do so and an example of how to use said program...)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Install `p7zip-full` on the server first and then run this to extract a z7 archive called `test.7z`, encrypted with the password `password`:

```
7z x test.7z -ppassword
```

As JanC adds below, you can omit the whole `-ppassword` flag and it will just ask you for the password on extraction:

```
oli@bert:~/Desktop$ 7z x test.7z

7-Zip 9.04 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-05-30
p7zip Version 9.04 (locale=en_GB.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)

Processing archive: test.7z

Enter password (will not be echoed) : <<I typed the password here>>

Extracting  botch2

Everything is Ok

Folders: 1
Files: 0
Size:       0
Compressed: 118
```

Comment: I think it also asks for the password if you don't give one on the commandline (which might be safer if multiple users use the server).

Comment: I can confirm that is true.

Comment: Anywhay this can be done via gui?

Comment: @tinhead Right click the file, click extract, bung in the password. I thought this was the out-the-box behaviour but in case it isn't, I have the `file-roller`, `lzma` and `p7zip-full` packages installed. Install some of them and try again.

Comment: Well that's great. Spent 10 hours compressing, turns out that `-p='my passphrase'` is not the right argument format. Fileroller didn't want to compress it, hanging itself after gathering a list of files, so had to use the command line. Can't figure out what the pwd is. It's not `my passphrase`, `'my passphrase'`, `='my`, `='my passphrase'` or `='my passphrase`. Great. Starting compressing again, this time with argument `-pmy\ passphrase`, that seemed to work (tested it this time around)... Edit: Also `-mhe=on` might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @Luc: You've spent 10 hours compressing without testing it first?

Comment: Woah! File barf everywhere! Set the output directory so all extracted files go into it with the `-o` flag! Assuming I want my output files to all be extracted to **outputdir**, for instance, I'd do: `7z x -ooutputdir myfile.7z`. Ahhhh, much better!

Answer (score -1):

there is a [rarcrack](http://rarcrack.sourceforge.net/) to do this task. It can handle .rar, .zip and .7z files. Check out this article:

http://mediakey.dk/~cc/howto-crack-rar-7z-and-zip-files-in-linux/

Hope this will help

Comment: tnx for this, but I know the password, just need to extract this :)

Comment: `rarcrack` is also pretty awful with its false positives. I tested it on my test.7z from above and it kept exiting with wrong passwords.

Comment: Broken link, error 404.